# error 504 with a select mysql on a database with 10 millions rows

Tags: mysql, performance, cloud, database-performance, vps

I have to build a search engine with php that will search in a MySQL database (10 M+ rows).

The problem is that the script I made give me Error : 504 randomly, I think it is due to the fact that the DB is very big (10 Millions rows and 110 cols).

The problem is that I have done lot of optimization : 
- Indexes on importants fields
- using "limit 0,10".
- skipping "select *" for"select id,field_1,field_2..."
- Upgrading on a VPS cloud server with high perf (24 Go RAM, pro 2,4 Ghz,100 Go space memory).

HAs anyone advice to avoid crashing and 504 error ?

Thanks !

Comment: 10 millions ( i guess you mean rows, lines doesnt make sense) is nothing i work with 120 millions very easy

Comment: Wow 120 millions ! Impressive !
Which kind of server do you use ?
Has your DB as special structure ?

Comment: nothing fancy 4 core 8 gb ram Is all about indexes

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) and

Comment: The problem I have is that I often have a 504 error when I execute the query, when I don't have an error it takes 1min or more to have results...

Comment: I used "EXPLAIN" and  I ve got this : 
Array
( 
    [id] => 1 
    [select_type] => SIMPLE 
    [table] => my_stock_1
    [type] => index 
    [possible_keys] => FIELD_1,FIELD_2,FIELD_3,FIELD_4,FIELD_5,FIELD_6 
    [key] => FIELD_7 
    [key_len] => 753  
    [ref] =>  
    [rows] => 17 
    [filtered] => 100.00 
    [Extra] => Using where
)

Comment: What actions are being performed when the 504 occurs?  What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` say then?  Does the cloud have any metrics?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for that table.

Comment: 10M rows is about the 90th percentile.  That is, 10% of tables are bigger than that.  I've seen a billion-row table run happily in 32GB of RAM.

Comment: @Neiluj - You showed us part of a `SELECT`, but left out parts that could be complex.

Comment: @Neiluj - are you going through the Internet?  Does your ISP have limits?  Is a web server involved?  What are its settings?  Check your local logs for details.

Comment: @Neiluj - are you using PHP?

Comment: Yes I am using php.
Sometimes I submit a form to search in the DB, one time I have a 504 error and one I time the query run well...

Comment: basicaly when I submit a form I launch 2 queries with mysqli_query.
One that counts the number of results with mysqli_num_rows and an other one that lists the 10 first results (limit 0,10)

Comment: I have check my log and when 504 occurs I get this in the log :

20294#0: *49479 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream

Comment: Include the explain plan as part of the question. Show us your code and the create table for the tables involve in the query. Do you have any error if run the query direct on the db?

Comment: The request is ok direct on the DB.
I found a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my err log as the error was a ngix error I looked in this direction and I found this page :

https://distinctplace.com/2017/04/22/nginx-upstream-timed-out/

So I modified this parameter : proxy_read_timeout // proxy_read_timeout = 600;
And the page load correctly (ti takes 20 to 50 seconds but it's ok).

Do you think it's a good solution ?

Thanks a lot for previous answers !